# Как сделать программу так чтобы на экран выводил то что я говорю

Tags: swift, xcode

Например : то что я буду говорит программe она должна записывать это в заметке

Comment: Никак. Наушники это выход, а не вход.

Comment: @Эникейщик кстати если вставить наушники в гнездо микрофона, то они будут работать как микрофон =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Как поганенький микрофон :) Но обычно там, где iOS, гнезда для микрофона вообще нет (вернее, оно было совмещено с гнездом для наушников, поэтому все равно бы не получилось), а с некоторых пор нет и гнезда для наушников.

Comment: @Эникейщик Как очень-очень поганенький микрофон :)

Comment: А без наушников можно сделать

Comment: А что, программ для распознавания речи под ios разве нету? Поищите, такие программы обязательно должны быть. И не одна и не две, а много.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 и искать не надо, достаточно в настройках активировать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться одной из существующих библиотек для распознвания речи. Например есть у Яндекс: [Yandex Speech Kit](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandex-speechkit-ios).

В iOS появилась стандартная библиотека для распознавания речи начиная с iOS 10, правда не могу сказать, на сколько хорошо она работает с русским языком. В этой статье написано подробно как использовать стандартный метод: [Speech recognition in iOS](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/speech-recognition-in-ios-only-available-from-ios-10-1da8a69df147).

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные iOS библиотеки для работы с речью есть. Смотрите в сторону SFSpeechRecognizer для записи и AVSpeechSynthesizer для воспроизведения. Я когда-то писал модуль с распознаванием текста для проекта, можете глянуть, возможно пригодится.

```
import AVFoundation
import Speech

class SpeachManager {
    static let sharedSpeachManager = SpeachManager()

    private var speachSyntesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    private var speachRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
    private var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
    private var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private var request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

    private var outputSoundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "outputSoundQueue")
    private var inputSoundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "inputSoundQueue")

    func textToSpeech(text: String, isTarget: Bool)
    {
        outputSoundQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.readText(text: text, rate: 0.3, isTarget: isTarget)
        }
    }

    func textToSpeech(text: String, withRate rate: Float, isTarget: Bool) {
        outputSoundQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.readText(text: text, rate: rate, isTarget: isTarget)
        }
    }

    private func readText(text: String, rate: Float, isTarget: Bool) {
        self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        if (SettingsManager.sharedSettingsManager.currentOutputSoundLanguage == Constants.defaultOutputSoundLanguage) {
            self.myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: searchForLanguage(isTarget: isTarget))
        } else {
            self.myUtterance.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: SettingsManager.sharedSettingsManager.currentOutputSoundLanguage)
        }
        self.myUtterance.rate = rate
        self.speachSyntesizer.speak(self.myUtterance)
    }

    private func searchForLanguage(isTarget: Bool) -> String {
        var result = "en-US"
        var languages = [String]()

        var valueToCheck = String()

        if (isTarget) {
            valueToCheck = SettingsManager.sharedSettingsManager.defaultLanguageTranslateTo?.shortIndex ?? "en-US"
        }
        else {
            valueToCheck = SettingsManager.sharedSettingsManager.defaultLanguageTranslateFrom?.shortIndex ?? "en-US"
        }

        getListOfOutputLanguages(list: &languages)

        if ((valueToCheck.count) < 3) {
            valueToCheck.append(String(format:"-%@", valueToCheck.uppercased()))
        }

        for l in languages {
            if (l == valueToCheck) {
                result = l
                break
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    func getListOfOutputLanguages(list: inout [String]) {
        for voice in (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()){
            list.append(voice.language)
        }
    }

    func recordTextFromMicrophone(completion: @escaping ((_ bestString: String) -> Void)) {
        inputSoundQueue.async {
            let note = self.audioEngine.inputNode
            let recordingFormat = self.audioEngine.outputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
            note.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, _) in
                self.request.append(buffer)
            }

            self.audioEngine.prepare()
            do {
                try self.audioEngine.start()
            }
            catch {
                return LogManager.sharedLogManager.writeMessageToLog(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()

            if (recognizer != nil) {
                if (recognizer!.isAvailable) {
                    self.recognitionTask = self.speachRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: self.request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
                        if result != nil {
                            let bestString = result!.bestTranscription.formattedString
                            completion(bestString)
                        } else {
                            if error != nil {
                                LogManager.sharedLogManager.writeMessageToLog(message: error!.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecrodingFromMicrophone() {
        inputSoundQueue.async {
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            self.request.endAudio()
            self.audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Поиск нужного языка вам вряд ли понадобится, подставьте там любой нужный вам язык.

Конверсия речи в текст:

```
@IBAction func buttonMichrophoneTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isMicrohponeActive) {
            isMicrohponeActive = false
            SpeachManager.sharedSpeachManager.stopRecrodingFromMicrophone()
            pulsator.stop()

            // call textViewDidChange
            self.textViewDidChange(viewTranslationFrom.textViewTranslateFrom)
            viewTranslationTo.textViewResult.hidePlaceholder()
        }
        else {
            isMicrohponeActive = true
            SpeachManager.sharedSpeachManager.recordTextFromMicrophone { (resultString) in
                self.viewTranslationFrom.textViewTranslateFrom.text = resultString
            }
            pulsator.start()

            viewTranslationFrom.textViewTranslateFrom.hidePlaceholder()
        }
    }
```

Конверсия текста в речь:

```
@IBAction func buttonSoundFromTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if (viewTranslationFrom.textViewTranslateFrom.text != "") {
            SpeachManager.sharedSpeachManager.textToSpeech(text: viewTranslationFrom.textViewTranslateFrom.text, isTarget: false)
        }
    }
```